# Removing a pointer from reflect.Type

Tags: go, reflection

I have a `reflect.Type` that contains a double-pointer to a struct. I'd like to be able to remove one level of indirection to have a pointer to the struct. Is this possible? For example, I'd like to do this:

```
func foo(x interface{}) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(x)
    fmt.Printf("%v", typ) // prints **Foo
    realType := typ.PointsTo()
    fmt.Printf("%v", typ) // prints *Foo
}
```

But as far as I can see, this functionality does not exist. There is an `Indirect` function that operates on `Value`s, but I can't see anything similar that works on `Type`s.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `Type.Elem()`.

Comment: That's it, thanks! If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`Type.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type):

> Elem returns a type's element type.

In the case of a pointer, the "element type" is the type the pointer points to.

```
func foo(x interface{}) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(x)
    fmt.Printf("%v", typ) // prints **Foo
    realType := typ.Elem()
    fmt.Printf("%v", realType) // prints *Foo
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7Vx58ASPZQz